# By default save all unknown media types when downloading

Tags: firefox, download

When downloading, Firefox asks whether to open or save files. I've read the [documentation](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/change-firefox-behavior-when-open-file) about this behaviour, but it seems you have to configure each media type separately.

On top of this, if the server specifies the media type incorrectly you can't set a default action.

Is there a way to just always save?

Answer (score 0):

I think such an option conflicts with the way the Firefox developers understand
the standards.

From
[Properly Configuring Server MIME Types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Configuring_server_MIME_types):

> **Why are correct MIME types important?**
>
> If the web server or
>   application reports an incorrect MIME type for content, a web browser
>   has no way, *according to the HTTP specification*, of knowing that the
>   author actually intended the content to be processed and displayed in
>   a way different from that implied by the reported MIME type.

In the past there existed one or two add-ons that could force this action,
but with Firefox discarding legacy-format add-ons, they have been lost.